# Running the code after an asynchronous task

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

So I am looking for a way to run only a block of code to run after an asynchronous task(s) have finished. The code is related to the `Request.executeAsync();` in the facebooksdk for android. The code that I going to use for the explanation is:

```
public class Home extends Activity {

    TextView welcomeTextView;
    private JSONObject userProfile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        userProfileFetched = false;

        welcomeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome);
        populateUserProfile();
        Log.d("USER_PROFILE", userProfile.toString()); //NullPointerException occurs here
    }

    private void populateUserProfile() {
        Request.newMeRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                userProfile = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
}
```

The line with the comment above points the line on which my app shuts down unexpectedly. When I first start the activity the `onCreate` method is called with some house keeping stuff. Then a function `populateUserProfile()` is called which executes a `me` request asynchronously. If I log the `response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().toString()` being in the `onCompleted()` function, I could clearly see the perfect result that I am looking for, the JSONObject for the logged in user but, as in the code above, if I assign that function's return value to the `userProfile` variable and then log it after the call of the function in the `onCreate()` method then my app stops unexpectedly and a NullPointerException is thrown at the `Log` line.

I know that this is happening because the `me` request is not yet completed while I log the `userProfile` JSONObject and that is why it's not assigned to anything yet, so I need to know how could I wait for the `onCompleted` method in the `populateUserProfile()` function so that the `userProfile` object could be successfully assigned to the info of the logged in user?

In other words, how could I wait for the asynchronous task of the `me` request to get finished and then log `userProfile` into the LogCat?

Hope I am clear and looking forward to an explanatory answer.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that comes to mind is to use `AsyncTask < T, T, T>` and then call your function in the `onPostExecute` method.

EDIT: This an example from `developers`, don't look what it does, just understand the concept. In the `doInBackground` method all the timetaking work is done, when it is finished it calls `onPostExecute`, hence you can safely assume that inside it all the Internet work is done and you can continue.

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     // here you call the function, the task is ended.

 }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you give me a little code snippet of how I could use that?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui The Android documentation has a good sample: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: You mean Log.i(...) ?

Comment: Maybe you didn't select your application in the logcat, chek under filters.

Comment: Log.d("USER_PROFILE", userProfile.toString()), the problem is in userProfile, meaning that the object is null, that is why you can't call toString() on something which doesn't exist. Try something like : Log.d("USER_PROFILE", "TEST").

Comment: @thecoder I told that I know the problem but I am still not able to eslove that. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
populateUserProfile(){

new AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void params) {
           return response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
           Log.d("USER_PROFILE", result.toString());
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: And where do I use that?

Comment: Can you integrte that piece of code into my code, I am unable to do that. :/

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Just get your `Response` object inside `populateUserProfile()` and you'll be able to execute your code